# Comparing a value by group based on date and creating new dataframe where value dropped

Tags: r, plyr, lubridate, dplyr

I've a df as under

```
+-----+------+--------+--------------------+------+---------+
| ID1 | ID2  | DOC_NO |        DATE        | COST | CLIENT  |
+-----+------+--------+--------------------+------+---------+
| ABC | A123 |      1 | 2021-01-01 0:10:00 |   11 | ABC123  |
| DEF | B456 |      2 | 2021-01-01 0:10:00 |   12 | DEF256  |
| GHI | C789 |      3 | 2021-01-01 0:10:00 |   13 | GHI389  |
| JKL | D890 |      4 | 2021-01-01 0:10:00 |   14 | JKL490  |
| MNO | E012 |      5 | 2021-01-01 0:10:00 |   15 | MNO512  |
| ABC | A123 |      6 | 2021-01-01 0:15:00 |   11 | ABC623  |
| DEF | B456 |      7 | 2021-01-01 0:15:00 |   12 | DEF756  |
| GHI | C789 |      8 | 2021-01-01 0:15:00 |   13 | GHI889  |
| JKL | D890 |      9 | 2021-01-02 0:15:00 |   14 | JKL990  |
| MNO | E012 |     10 | 2021-01-03 0:15:00 |   15 | MNO1012 |
| ABC | A123 |     11 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   10 | GHI890  |
| DEF | B456 |     12 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   11 | JKL991  |
| GHI | C789 |     13 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   12 | MNO1013 |
| JKL | D890 |     14 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   13 | GHI891  |
| MNO | E012 |     15 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   14 | JKL992  |
| ABC | A123 |     16 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   12 | MNO1014 |
| DEF | B456 |     17 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   13 | GHI892  |
| GHI | C789 |     18 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   14 | JKL993  |
| JKL | D890 |     19 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   15 | MNO1015 |
| MNO | E012 |     20 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   16 | GHI893  |
| ABC | A123 |     21 | 2021-01-03 0:25:00 |   11 | ABC124  |
| DEF | B456 |     22 | 2021-01-03 0:25:00 |   12 | DEF257  |
| GHI | C789 |     23 | 2021-01-03 0:25:00 |   13 | GHI390  |
| JKL | D890 |     24 | 2021-01-03 0:25:00 |   14 | JKL491  |
| MNO | E012 |     25 | 2021-01-03 0:25:00 |   15 | MNO513  |
+-----+------+--------+--------------------+------+---------+
```

I want to group ID1 and ID2 and arrange the df by DOC_NO and DATE
Post that I want to create a new column REFERENCE_COST, where the REFERENCE_COST is the highest cost with respect to time and DOC_NO arrangement, meaning if the COST increase with TIME and DOC_NO, the higher COST would now be set as a REFERENCE_COST
So the new df would look as under:

```
+-----+------+--------+--------------------+------+---------+----------+
| ID1 | ID2  | DOC_NO |        DATE        | COST | CLIENT  | REF_COST |
+-----+------+--------+--------------------+------+---------+----------+
| ABC | A123 |      1 | 2021-01-01 0:10:00 |   11 | ABC123  |       11 |
| DEF | B456 |      2 | 2021-01-01 0:10:00 |   12 | DEF256  |       12 |
| GHI | C789 |      3 | 2021-01-01 0:10:00 |   13 | GHI389  |       13 |
| JKL | D890 |      4 | 2021-01-01 0:10:00 |   14 | JKL490  |       14 |
| MNO | E012 |      5 | 2021-01-01 0:10:00 |   15 | MNO512  |       15 |
| ABC | A123 |      6 | 2021-01-01 0:15:00 |   11 | ABC623  |       11 |
| DEF | B456 |      7 | 2021-01-01 0:15:00 |   12 | DEF756  |       12 |
| GHI | C789 |      8 | 2021-01-01 0:15:00 |   13 | GHI889  |       13 |
| JKL | D890 |      9 | 2021-01-02 0:15:00 |   14 | JKL990  |       14 |
| MNO | E012 |     10 | 2021-01-03 0:15:00 |   15 | MNO1012 |       15 |
| ABC | A123 |     11 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   10 | GHI890  |       11 |
| DEF | B456 |     12 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   11 | JKL991  |       12 |
| GHI | C789 |     13 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   12 | MNO1013 |       13 |
| JKL | D890 |     14 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   13 | GHI891  |       14 |
| MNO | E012 |     15 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   14 | JKL992  |       15 |
| ABC | A123 |     16 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   12 | MNO1014 |       12 |
| DEF | B456 |     17 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   13 | GHI892  |       13 |
| GHI | C789 |     18 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   14 | JKL993  |       14 |
| JKL | D890 |     19 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   15 | MNO1015 |       15 |
| MNO | E012 |     20 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   16 | GHI893  |       16 |
| ABC | A123 |     21 | 2021-01-03 0:25:00 |   11 | ABC124  |       12 |
| DEF | B456 |     22 | 2021-01-03 0:25:00 |   12 | DEF257  |       13 |
| GHI | C789 |     23 | 2021-01-03 0:25:00 |   13 | GHI390  |       14 |
| JKL | D890 |     24 | 2021-01-03 0:25:00 |   14 | JKL491  |       15 |
| MNO | E012 |     25 | 2021-01-03 0:25:00 |   15 | MNO513  |       16 |
+-----+------+--------+--------------------+------+---------+----------+
```

No, I want to be able to compare the REFERENCE_COST with the COST and filter all rows where the COST was less than the REFERENCE_COST and also add two new columns DATE_LAST_REF_COST_MET & CLIENT_LAST_REF_COST_MET which shows the DATE of the REFERENCE_COST and the CLIENT number from that REFERENCE_COST
So the resulting df would be as under:

```
+-----+------+--------+--------------------+------+---------+----------+------------------------+--------------------------+
| ID1 | ID2  | DOC_NO |        DATE        | COST | CLIENT  | REF_COST | DATE_LAST_REF_COST_MET | CLIENT_LAST_REF_COST_MET |
+-----+------+--------+--------------------+------+---------+----------+------------------------+--------------------------+
| ABC | A123 |     11 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   10 | GHI890  |       11 | 2021-01-01 0:15:00     | ABC623                   |
| DEF | B456 |     12 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   11 | JKL991  |       12 | 2021-01-01 0:15:00     | DEF756                   |
| GHI | C789 |     13 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   12 | MNO1013 |       13 | 2021-01-01 0:15:00     | GHI889                   |
| JKL | D890 |     14 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   13 | GHI891  |       14 | 2021-01-02 0:15:00     | JKL990                   |
| MNO | E012 |     15 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00 |   14 | JKL992  |       15 | 2021-01-03 0:15:00     | MNO1012                  |
| ABC | A123 |     21 | 2021-01-03 0:25:00 |   11 | ABC124  |       12 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00     | MNO1014                  |
| DEF | B456 |     22 | 2021-01-03 0:25:00 |   12 | DEF257  |       13 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00     | GHI892                   |
| GHI | C789 |     23 | 2021-01-03 0:25:00 |   13 | GHI390  |       14 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00     | JKL993                   |
| JKL | D890 |     24 | 2021-01-03 0:25:00 |   14 | JKL491  |       15 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00     | MNO1015                  |
| MNO | E012 |     25 | 2021-01-03 0:25:00 |   15 | MNO513  |       16 | 2021-01-03 0:20:00     | GHI893                   |
+-----+------+--------+--------------------+------+---------+----------+------------------------+--------------------------+
```

This is what I was able to do :

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID1, ID2) %>%
  arrange(DATE, DOC_NO, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(diff = COST - lag(COST, default = first(COST)))%>%
  mutate(REF_COST = case_when(diff < 0~lag(COST), TRUE~diff)) %>%
  mutate(DATE_LAST_REF_COST_MET= case_when(diff < 0~lag(DATE), TRUE~DATE)) %>%
  mutate(CLIENT_LAST_REF_COST_MET= case_when(diff < 0~lag(CLIENT), TRUE~CLIENT))
```

The limitation with this is that it doesnt change the REFERENCE_COST with DATE and DOC_NO while making the calculations

I'm not sure how do I achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cummax` to set `REF_COST` and `lag` to get the previous value in each group. Use `filter` to keep only those rows where reference cost is higher than the cost.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID1, ID2) %>%
  mutate(REF_COST = cummax(COST), 
         DATE_LAST_REF_COST_MET = lag(DATE), 
         CLIENT_LAST_REF_COST_MET = lag(CLIENT)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(REF_COST > COST)

#    ID1   ID2   DOC_NO DATE                COST CLIENT  REF_COST DATE_LAST_REF_COST_MET CLIENT_LAST_REF_COST_MET
#   <chr> <chr>  <int> <chr>              <int> <chr>      <int> <chr>                  <chr>                   
# 1 ABC   A123      11 2021-01-03 0:20:00    10 GHI890        11 2021-01-01 0:15:00     ABC623                  
# 2 DEF   B456      12 2021-01-03 0:20:00    11 JKL991        12 2021-01-01 0:15:00     DEF756                  
# 3 GHI   C789      13 2021-01-03 0:20:00    12 MNO1013       13 2021-01-01 0:15:00     GHI889                  
# 4 JKL   D890      14 2021-01-03 0:20:00    13 GHI891        14 2021-01-02 0:15:00     JKL990                  
# 5 MNO   E012      15 2021-01-03 0:20:00    14 JKL992        15 2021-01-03 0:15:00     MNO1012                 
# 6 ABC   A123      21 2021-01-03 0:25:00    11 ABC124        12 2021-01-03 0:20:00     MNO1014                 
# 7 DEF   B456      22 2021-01-03 0:25:00    12 DEF257        13 2021-01-03 0:20:00     GHI892                  
# 8 GHI   C789      23 2021-01-03 0:25:00    13 GHI390        14 2021-01-03 0:20:00     JKL993                  
# 9 JKL   D890      24 2021-01-03 0:25:00    14 JKL491        15 2021-01-03 0:20:00     MNO1015                 
#10 MNO   E012      25 2021-01-03 0:25:00    15 MNO513        16 2021-01-03 0:20:00     GHI893
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in `dput` form which is easier to copy.

```
df <- structure(list(ID1 = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "ABC", 
"DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", 
"ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", 
"MNO"), ID2 = c("A123", "B456", "C789", "D890", "E012", "A123", 
"B456", "C789", "D890", "E012", "A123", "B456", "C789", "D890", 
"E012", "A123", "B456", "C789", "D890", "E012", "A123", "B456", 
"C789", "D890", "E012"), DOC_NO = 1:25, DATE = c("2021-01-01 0:10:00", 
"2021-01-01 0:10:00", "2021-01-01 0:10:00", "2021-01-01 0:10:00", 
"2021-01-01 0:10:00", "2021-01-01 0:15:00", "2021-01-01 0:15:00", 
"2021-01-01 0:15:00", "2021-01-02 0:15:00", "2021-01-03 0:15:00", 
"2021-01-03 0:20:00", "2021-01-03 0:20:00", "2021-01-03 0:20:00", 
"2021-01-03 0:20:00", "2021-01-03 0:20:00", "2021-01-03 0:20:00", 
"2021-01-03 0:20:00", "2021-01-03 0:20:00", "2021-01-03 0:20:00", 
"2021-01-03 0:20:00", "2021-01-03 0:25:00", "2021-01-03 0:25:00", 
"2021-01-03 0:25:00", "2021-01-03 0:25:00", "2021-01-03 0:25:00"
), COST = c(11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L), CLIENT = c("ABC123", "DEF256", "GHI389", "JKL490", 
"MNO512", "ABC623", "DEF756", "GHI889", "JKL990", "MNO1012", 
"GHI890", "JKL991", "MNO1013", "GHI891", "JKL992", "MNO1014", 
"GHI892", "JKL993", "MNO1015", "GHI893", "ABC124", "DEF257", 
"GHI390", "JKL491", "MNO513")), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This works great, but the one issue I have here is that, it pulls the lagging DATE and CLIENT, whereas I want it to show DATE and CLIENT from the same row of cummax(COST)
        ( DATE_LAST_REF_COST_MET = lag(DATE), 
         CLIENT_LAST_REF_COST_MET = lag(CLIENT)))

Not sure how do I achieve that

Comment: Hmmm...I don't know if I understand but this does give the same output as your expected output, right?

Comment: Its does partially, but the fields DATE_LAST_REF_COST_MET  and CLIENT_LAST_REF_COST_MET are actually just pulling the lagging values, instead I want them to pull values of the DATE and CLIENT from the same index as that of cummax(COST) value

Comment: Was just wondering if there was a way to get the index (row number) of cummax(COST) thats been used as REF_COST, so that I can use that I can look up DATE & CLIENT on that index value (row number) as the corresponding  DATE_LAST_REF_COST_MET & CLIENT_LAST_REF_COST_MET values

Comment: In that case, I think `df %>% group_by(ID1, ID2) %>% mutate(REF_COST = cummax(COST), row = row_number(), row = ifelse(REF_COST > lag(REF_COST, default = 0), row, NA)) %>% fill(row) %>% mutate(DATE_LAST_REF_COST_MET = DATE[row], CLIENT_LAST_REF_COST_MET = CLIENT[row]) %>%
  ungroup() %>% filter(REF_COST > COST) %>% select(-row)` should work but I don't think it gives the expected output shown.